# How can I duplicate ubuntu as image?

Tags: backup

I have setup y ubuntu with all kind of my setting 
now I want to duplicate it to 9 more computers (so I will have 10 exactly the same computers - with all the software\users\setting.....)
how I create an image and how do I install it on a new computer?
also if something happand to the computer I will be able to full restore it ?
Thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

You can make an OEM installation according to this link

[Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

and you can create a compressed image with Clonezilla. The image is a directory with a number of files, and you use Clonezilla to extract alias restore the system from the image to a drive (in the same or in other computers).

http://clonezilla.org

-o-

Install proprietary drivers only if you know that all the final computers will work with them.

If you want identical copies, you can skip the OEM bit, but OEM is usually a good idea, because the computers will get unique identities in the network, and the end users can create their own user IDs and passwords.

Comment: i don't think I need OEM - because I want all the computer to be the same , same user\password\etc.....       I have try to understand how to run it , but what do I need to save? I can see 3 Partition : FAT,ext4,swap - which one i need to backup ?

Comment: Clonezilla will save what needs to be saved, if you make an image of the whole drive. I suggest that you try the standard way with Clonezilla in 'beginner mode'. This is how I run it myself most of the time, although I have used it for several years. If the system you want to clone 'sits alongside other systems' you should grab only the relevant partition(s), but then you must fix with the bootloader and the swap manually afterwards.

Comment: OK , so let say I create a image of ex4 - how do I reinstall it on a new computer?

Comment: If you make an image of only the ext4 partition with Clonezilla (and not the whole drive) you have to create a partition with the same partition number and size (or bigger) and let Clonezilla restore into it. After that you have to install the grub bootloader, create a swap partition and make it match the entry in the file /etc/fstab.

Comment: It is not straight-forward at all. It might be as easy or easier to 'manually' create an ext4 partition and a swap partition with gparted, and if you intend to run in UEFI mode, an EFI partition with a FAT32 file system. After that run grub-install and create the bootloader. And finally make the entries in /etc/fstab and in /boot/grub/grub.cfg match the new partition structure. You can find many descriptions and tutorials of the details via the internet. We are no longer talking about duplication, but creating the partition structure and bootloader manually.